# UPDATE con INNER JOIN en Oracle 11G (Rendimiento)

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, plsql

Actualmente estoy empezando a trabajar con Bases de Datos en Oracle y es común tener que realizar UPDATE de una tabla a otra. Como las bases de datos que tengo acceso no tienen muchos registros, si ejecuto un Update con inner join no puedo evaluar el rendimiento del Update en tiempo. Pero hay una Db que tengo entendido tiene tablas con 50,000 registros o más.

Entonces quiero estar preparado para que si dado el caso debo modificar en las tablas en mención poder ejecutar una instrucción correctamente y no una que bloquee la db.

El update que utilizo regularmente es así:

```
UPDATE (
                SELECT Tabla1.Valor AS ValorAnterior
                    ,Tabla2.Codigo AS ValorNuevo
                FROM Tabla1
                INNER JOIN Tabla2 ON Tabla1.Valor = Tabla2.Descripcion
                WHERE Tabla1.Tipo = 1
                ) t
        SET t.ValorAnterior = t.ValorNuevo;
```

Por la red he visto las siguientes instrucciones:

```
1)   UPDATE Tabla1 SET Tabla1.Valor = (SELECT Tabla2.Codigo
                                          FROM Tabla2 
                                          WHERE Tabla1.Valor = Tabla2.Descripcion)
        WHERE Tabla1.Tipo=1
        AND EXISTS (SELECT Tabla2.Codigo
                    FROM Tabla2 
                    WHERE Tabla1.Valor = Tabla2.Descripcion);

2)        MERGE INTO Tabla1 trg
        USING (
            SELECT t1.RowId AS rid
                ,t2.Codigo
            FROM Tabla1 t1
            JOIN Tabla2 t2 ON Tabla1.Valor = Tabla2.Descripcion
            WHERE Tabla1.Tipo = 1
            ) src
            ON (trg.RowId = src.rid)
        WHEN MATCHED
            THEN
                UPDATE
                SET trg.Valor = Codigo;

3)        UPDATE (
                SELECT t1.Valor
                    ,t2.Codigo
                FROM Tabla1 t1
                INNER JOIN Tabla2 t2 ON t1.Valor = t2.Descripcion
                WHERE t1.Tipo = 1
                )
        SET t1.Valor = t2.Codigo;
```

Si alguien puede indicarme, la instrucción mas eficiente, muy agradecido.

Comment: Lo que recomendaría es que no utilizara `INNER JOIN` para hacer enlaces entre tablas ya que esta instrucción es más pesada, en cambio podría utilizar el `WHERE` tradicional para aumentar el rendimiento.

Comment: El rendimiento de una db, se mide al momento de ejecutar las consultas viendo los explain plan. Depende como este configurada la base, algo puede ser mejor o peor. No estoy para nada de acuerdo con el comentario anterior, ya que nada asegura que alguna u otra forma haga que algo vaya mas lento o mas rapido. Solo se puede saber, sabiendo la configuracion de la DB y las tablas. algo que para una tabla puede ser rapidisimo (por sus indices y sus datos), pueden ser lentisimo para otra.

Comment: Si ligas con los indices de las tablas correctamente y las funciones adecuadas del motor de base de datos , obtendrás el mayor rendimiento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo entendido que no hay diferencias de rendimiento entre usar conectores inner y left join con el formato antiguo (de hecho es mejor acostumbrarse a usarlos por un tema de orden en los querys). 
Además 50 mil registros no deberían darte problemas de rendimiento, Oracle es una base diseñada para trabajar con tablas de millones de registros.

Si tienes una BD replica (de desarrollo o testing) puedes hacer el ejercicio de ejecutar las instrucciones y hacer rollback luego.

- Ejecuto mi UPDATE1 -> Tomo el tiempo que demoro -> Aplico Rollback (Deshago todo el UPDATE1)
- Ejecuto mi UPDATE2 -> Tomo el tiempo que demoro -> Aplico Rollback (Deshago todo el UPDATE2)
- Y así sucesivamente...

Con eso puedes tener una estimación simple de rendimiento en tiempo, aparte de la información en costo que te da el plan de ejecución.

> Menciono que tengas una base replica para no cometer un error humano, ya que con Rollback técnicamente deshaces todo lo hecho, pero siempre puedes equivocarte, olvidar hacer rollback y terminar haciendo commit por otra parte, o tener activada la opción de autocommit en tu programa de gestión DB.